# Link to an android application from SMS/mail

Tags: android, hyperlink, sms

I would like to know if we can have a link in a SMS that would be handle by my application. For example a link which would look like myapp://blabla. And by clicking on it myapp would be open with the link as an argument.

This question also refers to email, either from a file with a special extension or a link like in the SMS.

Thanks a lot for your help.

---

Edit 31/01

Actually, I did what Greg suggested it but it doesn't work. Such a link (myapp://blabla) is not clickable in a SMS/email...When I replace myapp with http as a scheme, it works (Android asks me wether it should open the link with myapp or the browser). But myapp://blabla isn't clickable with myapp as a scheme.
Here is my code:

```
   <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
android:debuggable="true">
<activity android:name=".myapp"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
          android:launchMode="singleTask"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="blabla" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yep you can with an intent filter.

Basically in your android Manifest, choose an activity that you want to be the one that handles the given url.

```
<activity android:name=".myactivies.MyActivity">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
<data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="blabla" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Then inside your activity you can get the url by calling getData() on the intent.

Comment: Hi Greg. Actually, I did it but it doesn't work. Such a link (myapp://blabla) is not clickable in a SMS/email...When I replace myapp with http as a scheme, it works (Android asks me wether it should open the link with myapp or the browser). But myapp://blabla isn't clickable with myapp as a scheme. Any idea ?

Comment: can you post what you wrote? I find that the parser and model it generates are very lenient and it won't tell you when something is half configured, it just won't work

Comment: Hey I just flew through my stuff for a bit and realized you are correct. I am sorry. I wasn't thinking. So most of the text fields use android.text.Linkify to do the text linking within an app. That doesn't take into account non http urls. So unless you control the app rendering the text it won't work. So yeah we rely on the http urls for linkified sms's as well. I am really sorry about having you chase down a rabbit hole. What you can do is supply both intent filters and submit sms's with http and any app to app stuff you can do with your own custom scheme. Sorry again for the confusion.